# Selenium closing right after any request

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it due to the site himself? If it is the case, how to bypass the problem?

I tried to make the web driver wait, but it didn't help...

This is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
 
PATH = '/Users/xxxx/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://haveibeenpwned.com/')
e_mail = driver.find_element_by_id('Account')
e_mail.send_keys('contact@gmail.com')
login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('searchPwnage')
login_button.click()
response = driver.find_element_by_id('pwnCount')
print(response.text)
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://haveibeenpwned.com/')
e_mail = driver.find_element_by_id('Account')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `chromedriver` to stay open, you have to use the `detach` option when starting the `chromedriver`.
As the following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
```